# Customize bootstrap sass version to use outline:none;

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I need to override outline: none; using SASS version of bootstrap 3.3.2. I do see following mixin defined in bootstrap

```
@mixin tab-focus() {
  // Default
  outline: thin dotted;
  // WebKit
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Which is used for .btn in _button.scss as below excerpt

```
&:active,
  &.active {
    &:focus,
    &.focus {
      @include tab-focus;
    }
  }
```

But I don't know highlighted outline. I want none. Also I don't want to change the source code of bootstrap. Therefore I added custom_mixins.scss file and defined below

```
@mixin tab-focus() {
  // Default
  outline: none;
}
```

And used following order to compile bootstrap from sass source code. However its not taking my defined mixins. How can i do it?

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.2/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap";
@import "custom-mixins";
@import "custom-varaibles";
@import "html-controls";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand you should use:

```
 @import "bootstrap-sass-3.3.2/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap";

.btn {
  &,
  &:active,
  &.active {
    &:focus,
    &.focus {
      @include tab-focus;
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```

The above outputs:

```
.btn:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.active.focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  outline: none; }
```

In contrast to Less, sass does not compile both mixins with the same name into the CSS code. The last defined mixin has been used, but only when defined before usage. Also does sass not apply lazy loading. You can see the effect of the preceding when considering the following examples:

```
@mixin color() {
  size: 70px;
  color: red;
}

@mixin color() {
  color: green;
}

p {
@include color;
}
```

outputs:

```
p {
   color: green; }
```

whilst the following code:

```
@mixin color() {
  size: 70px;
  color: red;
}


p {
@include color;
}


@mixin color() {
  color: green;
}
```

outputs:

```
p {
  size: 70px;
  color: red; }
```